# How to call multiple hub method from SignalR

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am using SignalR and MVC.

I have developed an admin page where I can send notifications. There is a menu with an icon to display the unread notification.

If I click on the count a notification panel will display with the latest 5 notifications.

There is also a "View All" link which opens a new page to show all the notifications. If admin add new notification, I want to update the notification count as well as the view "All notification" page.

How can I call both the hub method on admin send button? I am expecting to see the newly added Notification in the `ViewAllNotification` page without refreshing. Expecting SignalR to push the data.

I have followed http://venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/ for my development.

Here i am not using sql dependency. On Send button(Admin screen) i am calling the hub methods to push notification

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.connection.hub.logging = true;
            var proxy = $.connection.broadcastMessage;

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#button1').click(function () {
                    proxy.server.broadcastNotifications($("#Message").val());
                    proxy.server.sendMessages();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is the Hub method.

```
    public class BroadcastMessage: Hub
        {
        public void BroadcastNotifications(string message)
        {         
            Utility.AddNotification(message);

            int UnreadCount = Utility.getUnreadMessageCount();

            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<BroadcastMessage>();
            context.Clients.All.receiveNotification(message, UnreadCount);
        }

        public static void SendMessages()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<BroadcastMessage>();
            context.Clients.All.updateMessages();
        }
    }
```

I have tried the above jQuery and signal r to call method one by one. But this doesn't work. It calls the first method and the second one didn't get invoked.

```
@model IEnumerable<Notification>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>ViewAllNotifications</h2>
<div class="container">
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NotificationID)</th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Message)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedDate)
        </th>

    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NotificationID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)
        </td>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedBy)
        </th>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            debugger;
            $.connection.hub.logging = true;
            var proxy = $.connection.broadcastMessage;

            proxy .client.updateMessages = function () {
                getAllMessages()
            };
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                alert("connection started")

                getAllMessages();
            }).fail(function (e) {
                alert(e);
            });
            function getAllMessages() {
                var tbl = $('#messagesTable');

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Notifications/GetMessages',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'html'
                }).success(function (result) {
                    tbl.empty().append(result);
                }).error(function () {

                });
            }

        });
</script>
```

Above is the partial view.And i was referring to http://venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/ 
My req is to push notification to this page whenever admin send notifications.

Comment: Do you get any javascript error ?

Comment: I assume broadcastMessage is the Hub? and remove static from SendMessages.

Comment: No JS error. .....@Tez : broadcastMessage is the Hub

Comment: Removed static from SendMessages. But no luck

Comment: You cannot call two methods like that...What you can do is either create two hubs, two methods or Call one hub method that then fires another method - If I ever needed a scenario like that, I used the latter. In all reality if you inherit from the Hub and all resides in one process you don't need to add the "GetHubConext"

Comment: @tez - i really feel i missed some thing in the signal r client code

Answer (score 1):

This is on the assumption that all dependencies are in the same process, If so you do not need `GetHubContext`

You should reorganise the logic like so:

**Hub**

```
[HubName("messageHub")]
public class MessageHub: Hub
{
    public void BroadcastNotifications(string message)
    {         
        Utility.AddNotification(message);
        int UnreadCount = Utility.getUnreadMessageCount();
        Clients.All.receiveNotification(message, UnreadCount);

        SendMessages();
    }

    public void SendMessages()
    {
        Clients.All.updateMessages();
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        var messageHub = $.connection.messageHub;

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#button1').click(function () {
                messageHub.server.broadcastNotifications($("#Message").val());
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried the above .The hub method is getting called. But the client side code at the viewAllNotification Page is not getting executed.I have updated the question with the partial view. Can you Please have a look and help me to resolve

Comment: @Tex- I really feel i made some mistake in client code (in my view). Unable to get any alerts there. If i look at the page source i can find the signal r call there

Comment: @jubi use the browser dev tools to check http requests.

Comment: @jubi Let me get something working. I'll give you a shout once done.

Comment: Thank you.Let me know if you need any details of my code

Comment: I was reading your answer and got a query on "This is on the assumption that all dependencies are in the same process, If so you do not need GetHubContext".  I do not need getHubContext . Can you explain me briefly.

Answer (score 0):

You should chain the calls, one after another, like this:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $('#button1').click(function () {
            proxy.server.broadcastNotifications($("#Message").val()).done(function () {
                proxy.server.sendMessages();
            });        
        });
    });
```

**UPDATE**

Referring to my comment below, you will need to add some code to your `ViewAllNotifications` View to allow SignalR to refresh it.  You are presently rendering the data on the server-side, so SignalR won't cause a reload.

you can try this, but I would recommend you rethink your approach like @Tez described.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        var proxy = $.connection.broadcastMessage;

        proxy.client.updateMessages = function () {
            location.reload();
            // reload the page from the server
        };

        $.connection.hub.start();   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have used the above code and it is exceuting the code now. Thank you for the response. But the client code is not getting executed. I mean , I have the ViewAllNotification Page opened where i can see all messafes . And admin entered a new notification through Add notification page .

Comment: I am expecting to see the newly added Notification in the ViewAllNotification page without refreshing. Expecting signal R to push the data.I have followed http://venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/ for my development. Here i am not using sql dependency. On Send button(Admin screen) i am calling the hub methods to push notification

Comment: let me review the question again.

Comment: It seems that you do not have any code on the ViewAllNotifications page to refresh the UI.  All of the rendering seems to be done through Razor.  you need to subscribe to hub on the ViewAllNotifications page  and call the `location.reload()` method OR rewrite your page so that you are rendering everything through SignalR / JavaScript

Comment: I have a view ViewAllNotification where i am having only one div and my scripts to recieve the signal r notification. My ajax code calls partial view and the result will be appened to the div mentioned above.Full code is added above